# Avoid having to repeat the same dataframe column names when modifying them

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe with over 30 columns. I am doing various modifications on specific columns and would like to find a way to avoid having to always list the specifc columns. Is there a shortcut?

For example:

```
matrix_bus_filled.loc[matrix_bus_filled['FNR'] == 'AB1122', ["Ice", "Tartlet", "Pain","Fruit","Club","Focaccia","SW of Month","Salad + Dressing","Planchette + bread","Muffin"]] = matrix_bus_filled[matrix_bus_filled['FNR'] == 'AB1120'][["Ice", "Tartlet", "Pain","Fruit","Club","Focaccia","SW of Month","Salad + Dressing","Planchette + bread","Muffin"]].values
```

Could I simply once define the term "SpecificColumns" and then paste it here?

```
matrix_bus_filled.loc[matrix_bus_filled['FNR'] == 'AB1122', ["SpecificColumns"]] = matrix_bus_filled[matrix_bus_filled['Flight Number'] == 'AB1120'][["SpecificColumns]].values
```

And here

```
matrix_bus_filled [["SpecificColumns"]] = matrix_bus_filled [["SpecificColumns"]].apply(scale, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define a list and use that to call the columns.

```
specific_columns = ["Ice", "Tartlet", "Pain","Fruit","Club","Focaccia","SW of Month","Salad + Dressing","Planchette + bread","Muffin"]

matrix_bus_filled[specific_columns] = matrix_bus_filled[specific_columns].apply(scale, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to change all of my code then? I see that you took off the double [[ in my code and only placed one

Comment: It is essentially the same thing, you were defining the list within the call to the DF instead of assigning the list to a variable. Therefore you only use single brackets and pass it a list.